# Mysql: Group by name of books (but by last updated cost too)

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to display all the products that the customer (ID) usually consume, and some products have special price. Of course, the customer can buy the same product again, but maybe with another price..

```
Structure orders table
CREATE TABLE orders (
order_id mediumint(8) unsigned not null auto_increment,
cl_id mediumint(8) unsigned not null default '0',
order_date int(10) unsigned not null default '0',
order_note varchar(255) not null default '',
PRIMARY KEY (order_id),
KEY cl_id (cl_id)
);
```

So, this is my sql:

```
SELECT cl.cl_name, or.order_id, pro.pro_name, detal.detal_price
FROM consumers cl
LEFT JOIN orders or
ON cl.cl_id = or.cl_id
LEFT JOIN order_detail detal
ON or.order_id = detal.order_id
LEFT JOIN products pro
ON detal.pro_id = pro.pro_id
WHERE cl.cl_id = 5
GROUP BY pro.pro_name
```

Ok, I use "group by" to not repeat the same product name. But I need to show price too, but last updated price. I think need to use "order_date", but I need some help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick to get the last price:

```
SELECT c.cl_name, p.pro_name,
       substring_index(group_concat(d.detal_price order by order_date desc), ',', 1) as MostRecentPrice
FROM consumers cl LEFT JOIN
     orders o
     ON c.cl_id = o.cl_id LEFT JOIN
     order_detail detal
     ON o.order_id = d.order_id LEFT JOIN
     products p
     ON d.pro_id = p.pro_id
WHERE c.cl_id = 5
GROUP BY c.cl_name, p.pro_name;
```

I made a few other changes to the query:

- Fixed the table aliases.  Because `or` is a keyword in SQL, it is a bad choice for a table alias.  I shorted all of them.
- Added `c.cl_name` to the `group by`.  This is not needed in MySQL, but it would be in other dialects.  Plus, it is a good habit to avoid errors in queries.
- Removed `order_id`.  This is rather meaningless in your query, because you are not aggregating at the order level.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I appreciate it.